# How to extract a table using camelot

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract a table from a sample pdf, the problem is that the table doesn't have lines within it to separate columns.

This is a picture of the document:

[image]

When I try running:

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf(filename)
print(tables[0].df)
```

It prints the right table content but with no regard of the columns, it treats the whole table as one single column, like this:

```
0  Credit  \nDate  \nReference No.  \nDescription...
1  09/10/2016  \n3194949206  \nOnline Banking tra...
2  09/20/2016  \n3194749206  \nOnline Banking tra...
3  09/20/2016  \n34236757678  \nCA TLR cash withd...
4  10/08/2016  \n5444  \nInterest  \n            ...
```

And when I run this:

```
print(tables[0].df.shape)
```

The result is (5, 1).

I tried another solution with specifying the stream like this:

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf(filename, flavor='stream')
```

But then it will get and print the wrong data, this is the result:

```
                                0                                   1
0                  Bank of Domino                                    
1                                        Customer service information
2                  P.O. Box 15001                        1.888.DOMINO
3             Arlington, VA 18505  TDD/TTY users only: 1.800.288.4101
4                                          En Espanol: 1.800.688.6229
5  Account Number: 00000970987652                    bankofdomino.com
6                     ROBERT BELL                Bank of Domino, N.A.
7              HOLLOW WAY,APT 503                      P.O. Box 25125
8         SAN MESA, CA 92627-5125                   San Mesa,CA 33390
```

And the shape of the df is (9, 2).

I also tried specifying the columns x coordinates but to no avail:

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf(filename, flavor='stream', columns="10, 120, 230, 470, 520, 650, 720, 800")
```

It still gets the wrong data.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: here's the pdf sample.

https://mega.nz/file/cNtwDSpI#KuhG03P1Qg5kLa69jZ7ohb3FF8G6ITNuMFsFyQVMudw

Comment: Are you set on `camelot` or are you're ok with other libraries as well? and is there a way we can download or get access to the pdf itself?

Comment: @LidorEliyahuShelef Any other library will do, thanks. As for the pdf file I got it from the Automation Anywhere sample files for training the IQ bot (I hate RPA, that's why I decided to automate it using python). I'll upload it and update my post.

Comment: @LidorEliyahuShelef Sure, I've updated the post with the pdf link: https://mega.nz/file/cNtwDSpI#KuhG03P1Qg5kLa69jZ7ohb3FF8G6ITNuMFsFyQVMudw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so you have a few options, I'll give you a few examples with your sample pdf file:

#### Option 1, using `tabula-py`:

```py
import tabula

pdf_path = dir_path + "/bankk.pdf"
tb = tabula.read_pdf(pdf_path, pages='all')
```

This will give you a list of dataframes of all the tables it detected in your pdf, using `tb[0]` will give the following result:

```py
+----------+-------------+--------------------+---------+-------+----------+
|      Date|Reference No.|         Description|   Credit|  Debit|   Balance|
+----------+-------------+--------------------+---------+-------+----------+
|09/10/2016|   3194949206|Online Banking tr...|$2,500.00|   null|$14,000.49|
|09/20/2016|   3194749206|Online Banking tr...|$3,800.00|   null|$17,800.49|
|09/20/2016|  34236757678|CA TLR cash withd...|     null|$300.00|$17,500.49|
|10/08/2016|         5444|            Interest|    $0.64|   null|$17,501.13|
+----------+-------------+--------------------+---------+-------+----------+
```

#### Option 2, using `pandas` and `pdfplumber`:

```py
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd

pdf = pdfplumber.open(pdf_path)
page = pdf.pages[0]
tb = page.extract_table(table_settings={"horizontal_strategy": "lines",  
                                        "vertical_strategy": "text",
                                        "keep_blank_chars": "text",
                                         "snap_tolerance": 5,})
df = pd.DataFrame(tb[1:], columns=tb[0])
```

> Note that you might need to play with the `table_settings`, to read
> more refer to [this link](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber)

#### Option 3, using AWS Textract ([Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7018582/thomas) edit):

You can use the `amazon-textract-textractor` [package](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-textract-textractor) to call textract and parse its output. The advantage of Textract is that it works for native pdfs, scanned pdfs, or images. For example with your image:

```
from textractor import Textractor
from textractor.data.constants import TextractFeatures
extractor = Textractor(profile_name="default")
document = extractor.analyze_document(
    file_source="./N6klE.png",
    features=[TextractFeatures.TABLES],
)
```

Textract detects the two tables:

```
document.tables[1].to_pandas(use_columns=True)
```

[image: pandas df2]

#### Option 4, using Deep Learning

Use deep learning algorithms to train a model to detect the tables on every page of the pdf and then use `pytesseract` to get the table data, you can refer to my article in [Medium](https://medium.com/) for getting the table data after detection here: [Image Table to DataFrame using Python OCR](https://medium.com/@lidores98/image-table-to-dataframe-using-python-ocr-773c8afb713d)

---

Of course, you can always still use `camelot` but I prefer `tabula-py` for simple solutions and deep learning for more complex ones

Comment: Thank you so very much, this was more detailed and had many options than I would've expected from an answer. I really can't thank you enough.

Comment: You're very welcome, we are all here to help each other when we can :)

Comment: I've Just tried to edit '''verticle_strategy''' to '''vertical_strategy'''. Not sure if it's edited for everyone.

Comment: I've edited it, it was a typo, thank you